# What is the best way(s) to deal with traffic in a highway's entrance/exit?

Tags: cities-skylines

Every highway's entrance or exit is causing traffic problem.

[image]

As you can see, there is a small road that immediately goes in the large road.

What is the best way(s) to deal with traffic in a highway's entrance/exit? Is there something I'm doing wrong with the highway on the picture?

Comment: [tag:murder] everyone in the city, then you won't have to worry about traffic anymore. :)

Comment: Follow the line of traffic to the other end. The other end of the gridlock is the important part